# Images get resized on scaling in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using CSS to scale images but when I resize the window all images scale down in different sizes ( see attached image).  Any clues what I need to do to get this to be responsive
[image]

```css
.boxcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  width: 336px;
  height: 336px;
  float: left;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxcontainer">
  <div class="textheader">New</div>
  <a href="https://my server.com/pages/121/new">
    <img src="https://cdn5.dcbstatic.com/files/n/y/myserver/userfiles/54340/no.png" class="image" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: because every image have different aspect ration/dimentions, some images will have square dimension or some have landscape, so as you have given auto to template columns image is automatically resize based upon their aspect ration.

Comment: All images are  size  336px * 336px

Answer (score 0):

`object-fit` + `object-size` + `object-position` CSS property can help you to move the img inside a fixed-size container

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what properties have to be set ?

Comment: the mimics the background-image properties. lets say i have a frame 200px X 350px but the the image is different ratio, lets say 210*210. you can fit the whole pic but then you'll be left with empty spaces, you can stretch the img above all the frame but you'll leave some parts of the img out (`object-fit`). if you so - you have the ability to decide what parts will be in and what parts out (`object -position`). etc.